# How do I install the libg2c0 library?

Tags: installation, package-management

I am trying to install the library libg2c0, which is required for the package xfoil. However this package is unavailable at ubuntu 12.04. I tried the suggestions from https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/view/Sandbox/HCALRadiationProject:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

I added the following lines at the end of the file:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy main universe 
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy main 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy-updates main universe 
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy-updates main universe
```

Update the list and install the library:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libg2c0
```

When these commands are executed I get the error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libg2c0 : Depends: gcc-3.4-base (= 3.4.6-6ubuntu5) but it is not going to be installed
```

Additionally I tried to install the package from [UbuntuPackages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/i386/libg2c0/download), but this did not work either.

I hope you can give me some hints about how to solve this problem. Would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems for me you have some package pinnings.

#### dpkg way

But either way, just download those packages (`libg2c0`, `gcc-3.4-base`, `gcc-3.4`, `cpp-3.4`) with wget and install them directly with dpkg. With some command line fu:

```
PACKAGES=(libg2c0 gcc-3.4 gcc-3.4-base cpp-3.4)
for pkg in $PACKAGES; do wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//pool/universe/g/gcc-3.4/${pkg}_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_$(dpkg --print-architecture).deb; done
sudo dpkg -i ${PACKAGES/%/_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_$(dpkg --print-architecture).deb}
```

There is no need for the hardy package sources with this method.

#### APT way

An alternate method with the hardy sources enabled would be to set up some package pinnings in `/etc/apt/preferences`:

```
Package: libg2c0 gcc-3.4 gcc-3.4-base cpp-3.4
Pin: release a=hardy*
Pin-Priority: 500

Package: *
Pin: release a=hardy*
Pin-Priority: -1
```